# Count the number of neighbors for each node in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a new property for each node that is the number of nodes they are connected to with a relationship. Like, for each actor in the example graph have the count of movies they are in.

Answer (score 0):

First set it to zero for everyone because some people won't have any movies:

```
MATCH (v:Person)
SET v.movies = 0
```

Then the key is to use a `WITH` clause, otherwise aggregation doesn't work.

```
MATCH (v:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH v, count(*) AS movies
SET v.movies = movies
```

Comment: I'm self-answering this because after reading the docs and a lot of Stack Overflow answers it still took me ages to find the solution. Apologies if this is obvious to everyone else.

Comment: Note also that if this is just for efficiency in storage, and if it's okay to consider the count of relationships (ignoring the possibility of multiple relationships from a node pointing to the same other node), then it's just as efficient to query for the degree with `MATCH (v:Person) RETURN size((v)-[:ACTED_IN]->())`. That is quick and doesn't require expansion, as long as you don't need to know anything about the node at the other end.